# "Type object 'GeometryType' has no attribute 'LineGeometry'" error when exporting shapefile to SVG

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-plugins, export, svg

I want to export a shapefile to SVG. It's a simple shapefile from Germany that I downloaded from https://www.eea.europa.eu/ and applied some changes as I wanted. I downloaded [SimpleSVG](https://github.com/rduivenvoorde/simplesvg) plugin but it raises an error. I tried exporting only the original shapefile but still the error is there.

This is the error I get:

```
AttributeError: type object 'GeometryType' has no attribute 'LineGeometry' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fateme/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/simplesvg/SimpleSvg.py", line 155, in writeToFile
    output = self.writeSVG()
  File "/home/fateme/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/simplesvg/SimpleSvg.py", line 214, in writeSVG
    svg.extend(self.writeVectorLayer(layer, False))
  File "/home/fateme/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/simplesvg/SimpleSvg.py", line 336, in writeVectorLayer
    sym = self.createSymbol(feature, symbol, layer)
  File "/home/fateme/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/simplesvg/SimpleSvg.py", line 433, in createSymbol
    if QgsWkbTypes.geometryType(geom.wkbType())  == QgsWkbTypes.GeometryType.LineGeometry:
AttributeError: type object 'GeometryType' has no attribute 'LineGeometry'
```

Comment: Have you tried converting your shapefile from polygon to line (vector -> geometry tools -> polygons to lines) and then exporting?

Comment: @Erik Yes I tried. I also tried check validity but none of them worked

Comment: And have you got into contact with the supplier of the plugin or searched for similar bug reports?

Answer (score 5):

For a temporary solution:

- Navigate to `/home/fateme/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/simplesvg`
- Open `SimpleSvg.py` file in a text editor.
- Find all `QgsWkbTypes.GeometryType.LineGeometry` text.
- Change all to `1`.
- Save and restart QGIS.